# python script that would move zip folders to new directory based on their names

Tags: python, zip, movefile

I am trying to write a script in python which could allow me to move zip files to a new folder based on their names, but I am struggling with it as I cannot figure out how to make python read the zip files name and move it to relevant folders. Any help would be appreciated.

zip file names are
12345788_CATPICC1_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip
90234578_CATPICC1_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip
96352536_CATPICC2_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip
78541296_CATPICC2_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip

Folders where above zip files need to go:
Markky wool (CATPICC1)
Markky wool (CATPICC2)

when moving zip file python needs to read CATPICC1 from 12345788_CATPICC1_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip and move it to Markky wool (CATPICC1) and if zip file name is 78541296_CATPICC2_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip then move it to Markky wool (CATPICC2)

i have thousands of files like these and i want to move each of them to a folder with matching name e.g., 12345788_CATPICC1_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip to Markky wool (CATPICC1)

Comment: use `os.listdir` + filter by extension or smt like directly `glob.glob('*.zip')`

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do... you have thousand of zip-files, but you want to move all of them or only those which satisfy a certain pattern? Are they on the same folder? Please, edit your question to make it more understandable (also your attempt would be useful!)

Comment: Thank you i have edit the question. really appreciate your guidance. Basically I want to move each zip file to their corresponding folder. I can move one file at a time but i want to move them in one go and thats what causing me confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, accounting for your own OS and filepaths:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import shutil

path = Path.cwd()  # insert your path

files = []

for file in path.rglob('*.zip'):  # loop recursively over all subdirectories
    files.append(file.name)

print(files)

for f in files:
    x = f.rsplit('_')
    x = x[1]
    print(x)

    if x == "CATPICC1":
        shutil.move("./files/"+f, './CAT1/'+f)
    if x == "CATPICC2":
        shutil.move("./files/"+f, './CAT2/'+f)
```

Comment: This is what i have written so far but it moves only one folder 

import glob
import os
import shutil

src_folder = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test python"
dst_folder = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test python\Markky wool (CATPICC1) "

# move file whose name starts with string 
pattern = src_folder + "\12345788_CATPICC1_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip*"
for file in glob.iglob(pattern, recursive=True):
    shutil.move(file, dst_folder)
    print('Moved:', file)

Comment: i have very basic knowledge of python so i do not know how could i do what you mentioned above in your comments

Comment: [Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\New Text Document.py", line 5, in <module>
    path = path.cwd(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\Markky wool(CATPICC1)")
NameError: name 'path' is not defined]

Comment: I am getting error from following code:
[from pathlib import Path
import os
import shutil

path = path.cwd(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\Markky wool(CATPICC1)")

files = []

for file in path.rglob('*.zip'):  # loop recursively over all subdirectories
    files.append(file.name)

print(files)

for f in files:
    x = f.rsplit('_')
    x = x[1]
    print(x)

    if x == "CATPICC1":
        shutil.move("./files/"+f, './CAT1/'+f)
    if x == "CATPICC2":
        shutil.move("./files/"+f, './CAT2/'+f)
]

Comment: Interesting. I set up a test directory with .zip files named as you outlined above and this did the trick. I do not have anything in the parenthesis for the path variable. I am also on Linux so my directories will look different from yours. If you are new to programming, take the stack trace one step at a time and work on the problem.

Comment: @TheDataScienceNinja you are using a unix-like path format instead (from the previous comment) the OP has a windows one. Use `os.sep` and `os.join` to get a platform independent solution

Comment: Thank you for your advice. @cards how can i use os.sep or os.join in the above code ?

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried already? Which parts are working and which parts aren't?

This problem can be broken down into a few parts:

1. Collect all file names
2. Match substrings in file names
3. Move files

Here's the pseudocode for what you're trying to do:

```
# There are fancier ways to accomplish this, but I 
# think this is the easiest to understand.
names_list = get_file_names("in_this_folder")
for files in names_list:
    if file_name contains "string1":
        move(file_name,"to_this_folder")
    elif file_name contains "string2":
        move(file_name,"to_other_folder")
    else:
        do nothing?
```

To collect filenames in a directory, you might do something like this

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil # Notice! We're importing this for later in the answer.

# Define folder structure
basepath = Path().resolve()
zip_folder = basepath.joinpath("zip/to-be-processed")
destination_folder_1 = basepath.joinpath("zip/done/01")
destination_folder_2 = basepath.joinpath("zip/done/02")

# Create destination folders if they don't already exist
Path(destination_folder_1).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 
Path(destination_folder_2).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 


def get_file_names(path: Path, extension: str):
    # Returns file names in path that match "*" + "extension"
    names = os.listdir(path)
    file_names = []
    for i in range(len(names)):
        # Look for the extension, case-insensitive.
        if names[i].lower().endswith(extension.lower()):
            file_names.append(names[i])
    return file_names

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a list of the file names that looks something like this:
    # ["file1.zip", "file2.zip", "etc..."]
    file_names = get_file_names(zip_folder,"zip")
    
    # Now move on to processing the list...
```

Now you have a list of all zip file names in the directory. Next, you'll find the substrings that you're interested in. You can use the `.find()` string method for this. If the string that you're looking for exists in the string that you're searching, then `find()` will return the position. **If the string isn't found, then it returns -1.**

Note that it's sometimes good idea to use `.lower()` or `.upper()` on both your candidate string and the substring that you're looking for (so you can find ".zip" and ".ZIP" files, for example).

```
>>> foo = "12345788_CATPICC1_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip"
>>> bar = "12345788_CAICC1_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip"                                                                     
>>> foo.lower().find("CATPICC1".lower())                                                                                  
9                                                                                                                       
>>> bar.lower().find("CATPICC1".lower())                                                                                  
-1
```

Example of use:

```
# Look for the substring "special" in each of the file names.
file_names = ["file_1_special.zip","file_2.zip"]
for name in file_names:
    if name.find("special") > -1:
        # Do something
        print("Found the file.")
    else:
        # Do something else.
        print("Where are you????")
```

Then use `shutil.move()` to move a file.

```
# File name as a string, just like we created earlier.
file_name = "moveme.zip"
# Move it.
shutil.move(zip_folder.joinpath(file_name),destination_folder_2)
```

**Note that I'm making assumptions about your directory structure and where the files live in relation to your script. You will have to modify accordingly. Please look up `pathlib.Path.resolve()` to understand what I did.**

Comment: i will try this and get back to you, your code is really high level and i am trying to work out what is happening but i am getting confused. btw i am just a beginner who just started learning python so apologies if i sound thick

Comment: All of the pieces are there, you just have to assemble them. You'll need to modify the "do something/do something else" conditional to get this thing up and running. (Aside: I just edited a few things for clarity.)

Comment: @picobit your `zip_folder` and `destination_folder`s are platform dependent (the OP has windows OS). Use `os.path.join` in combination with `os.sep` to have a platform independent solution

Comment: @cards That's actually not necessary as Path() instantiates either PosixPath or WindowsPath as needed. I wrote my example in Linux and just tested it in Windows to prove to myself that I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Used [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to list file and [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to move files. Since a lot file will be moved you can comment the `print`s inside the loop to save a bit of time. The program moves all files/dirs ending the a certain extension to a given (and existing) target directory.

```
import os 
import shutil


def mv_by_extension(wdir, dst, ext='.zip'):
    # dst as abs-path 
    if not os.path.isabs(dst):
        dst = os.path.abspath(dst) 

    print(f'Moving "{ext}"-file to target directory "{dst}"')
    # filter by extension and move file
    for fzip in filter(lambda path: path.endswith(ext), os.listdir(wdir)):
        file_zip = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(wdir, fzip))
        print(f'Moving file "{file_zip}"...')
        shutil.move(src=file_zip, dst=dst)
        print('... done!')
     
     print('Finished.')


wdir = # directory containg the zip-files
destination_dir = # path of the destination directory

mv_by_extension(wdir, destination_dir, ext='.zip')
```

---

Optimized solution - asynchronously execution with [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

```
import os 
import shutil
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

ext = '.zip'
wdir = # abs-path of exts dir
dst = #  abs-path of destination dir

# get files/dir by extension
zips = (os.path.abspath(path) for path in os.listdir(wdir) if path.endswith(ext))

# asynchro-moving
def amove(path, dst=dst):
    shutil.move(src=path, dst=dst)


print(f'Moving "{ext}" to target directory "{dst}" asynchronously.')
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
    exe.map(amove, zips)

print('...done.')
```

---

EDIT: filter files by rule (see comments)
Used [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to get more control on searching pattern.

```
import re

def filter_files(wdir, regex='', ext='zip'):
    pattern = re.compile(rf'{regex}\.(:?{ext})$')
    return (os.path.abspath(path) for path in os.listdir(wdir) if pattern.search(path))
```

All together

```
import os 
import shutil
import re
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def amove(path, dst=dst): # asynchro-moving
    shutil.move(src=path, dst=dst)

def filter_files(wdir, regex='', ext='zip'):
    pattern = re.compile(rf'{regex}\.(:?{ext})$')
    return (os.path.abspath(path) for path in os.listdir(wdir) if pattern.search(path))

# main
wdir = # abs-path of exts dir
dst1 = #  abs-path of destination dir for CATPICC1-like

# filter rules
regex1 = r'[0-9a-zA-Z]+_CATPICC1.+'
ext = 'zip' # without dot!

# get zip-files
zips1 = filter_files(wdir, regex1, ext)

# start asynchro-operation
print(f'Moving "{ext}" to target directory "{dst1}" asynchronously.')
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
    exe.map(amove, zips1)
print('...done.')
```

Do the same (or do all at once with an iteration using a *for*-loop) for the other case use the following regex `regex2 = r'[0-9a-zA-Z]+_CATPICC2.+'` and don't forget to update `dst2`.

Comment: thank you, this worked but it moved all of the zip file to dst folder, i want to move only those with specific names such as 12345788_CATPICC1_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip to CATPICC1 and 12345788_CATPICC2_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip to CATPICC2

Comment: I asked you in my 2nd comment of the question if there is a rule concerning the zip-names. Tell me the rule... it should be an easy fix but the rule should be exact. Do you know [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

Comment: that python script should ignore all of the letters, digits before CATPICC1 and only look at "CATPICC1" name from zip file 12345788_CATPICC1_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip. if zip file name contains "CATPICC1" it should move it to Markky wool (CATPICC1) and if zip file contains CATPICC2 (12345788_CATPICC2_2022_01_10_08_21_31.zip) then it should move the zip file to destination folder Markky wool (CATPICC2). the destination folders are already created so this script should only move the zip files to their created destination and avoid duplication

Comment: i dont know about regular expressions

Comment: if you are not sure about the result check first the output of `zips1` with a `print`. if it makes sense you are ready to move the files

Comment: perfect, it is working now awesome. Thank you so much mate, i really appreciate it

Comment: Good to hear that:) If you think that my post answer your question don't forget to check it